# Required request part 'payload' is not present Swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am trying to make a post request with Alamofire and getting Required request part 'payload' is not present and this is the first time I see or work on this kind of requests and as you can see in  code I have mediaType which can be text, image,...ect

**Note**: the payload is PayloadDto JSON

```
func send(){

  let body: [String:String] = [
                "text":message,
                "mediaType":"TEXT", //or image , video ,voice 
                "id":id
            ]

   let payload = [
                payload:"\(body)"
            ]

      Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { MultipartFormData in
                for (key, value) in payload {
                    MultipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
                }
            }, usingThreshold: UInt64.init(),
               to: "url",
               method: .post,
               headers:["Authorization": "access token"],
                encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                    switch encodingResult {
                    case .success(let upload, _, _):
                        upload.responseJSON { response in
                          print("response"\(response))
                                }
                                return
                            }
                        }
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print(error)
                    }
          })
}
```

Comment: `let payload = [payload:"\(body)"]` No. I think it should be `let payload = [payload: body]`.

Comment: this will cus error with  multipartFormData.append(value(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)

Comment: Value of type '[String : [String : String]]' has no member 'data'

Comment: `for (key, value) in payload {` => `for (key, value) in body {`. You don't seem ot use `payload`.

Comment: but I need the payload the the error I am getting is that the "Required request part 'payload' is not present Swift"